# Redirect resource path with Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My deployment and service, which is working fine,is available via `http://my.server.net:32142` - returns the JSON

Here is the output of Service

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
ok                NodePort    10.104.118.110   <none>        8080:32142/TCP   92m
```

Ingress:

```
NAME          HOSTS                    ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ok            my.server.net            80      86m
```

But i have a challenge with the Ingress which does not redirect me to my desired resource

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ok
  labels:
    app: ok
    system: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.server.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        backend:
          serviceName: ok
          servicePort: 8080
```

Expected Output:
`http://my.server.net/test` and `http://my.server.net:32142/test` should return the JSON at the moment it returns only a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use custom header in the request, so that your Ingress Controller can find routes for the right host for incoming traffic, otherwise you are hitting default backend (404), like this:

```
curl http://<IP_ADDRESS*>/test -H 'Host:my.server.net'
```

where `IP_ADDRESS` is the IP of LoadBalancer - your Ingress Controller's frontend, eventually you can try to use form `<IP_OF_NODE>:<NodePort>`, but it depends how you exposed your Ingress Controller.

Please read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting) more about Ingress configuration for so called: "Name based virtual hosting"